# Conflict with JQuery UI Datepicker and Tooltip widget

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, tooltip, conflict

In my html form there is a date field with a multiple line description in the title attribute which pops up in a tooltip. If the Datepicker calendar pops up, the Tootltip disappears as I move the mouse down over the calendar. Unfortunately, it pops back up as soon as I change the month through the NEXT button of the calendar and covers the button. So, I can never go further than one month ahead.

How can I work around this issue?

**Here is a sample of one date field:**

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="enddate" title="<b>Lorem ipsum :</b> Enddate<br><br>dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. " />
```

I am using JQuery 1.9.1.

Here is a JSFiddle that shows the problem. As soon as the next month in the calendar view is selected it is not possible to click NEXT again:
http://jsfiddle.net/gnuken/L0gxjLwq/1/

Comment: can you add a http://jsfiddle.net sample

Comment: I working on a sample.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gnuken/L0gxjLwq/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the jquery UI Docs the Tooltips is trigered using `focusin` or `mouseover`
http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#event-open

all what you have to do is turn off the `focusin` event  just use the `.off('focusin')` at the end of the tooltip declaration <kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abbasmhd/L0gxjLwq/2/)</kbd>

```
$(document).tooltip({
    position: {
        my: "left+15 center",
        at: "right center",
        collision: "flipfit"
    },
    content: function () {
        return $(this).prop('title');
    }
}).off('focusin');
```